# .NET 5 TargetFramework issue with referenced project when publishing WPF App over ClickOnce

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce, publish, .net-5

I'm trying to publish a WPF app with Target Framework net5.0-windows using ClickOnce (Built in VS2019), which has a Project Reference to another .NET5 Class Library.

But I always run into the following exception:

> Publish has encountered an error.
>
> Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details.

The diagnostic log shows me the exact exception:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details.
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> ---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details. <---
>
> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details.

The issue can be easily reproduced:

1. Create new Solution with a WPF project (.NET5)
2. Create new Class Library (.NET5) in this solution
3. Reference the ClassLibrary from the WPF App
4. Try to publish the WPF App with ClickOnce (right-click the WPF App project -> Publish -> ClickOnce, ...)

Here's a Demo project, which I've created followed the steps above:

**PublishDemo.Core (Class library)**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
   <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
   </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

**PublishDemo.Wpf (WPF App)**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
        <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\PublishDemo.Core\PublishDemo.Core.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The Build output displays the following error:

> Metadata file 'C:\work\source\unmanaged\PublishDemo\PublishDemo\PublishDemo.Core\bin\Release\net5.0-windows\PublishDemo.Core.dll' could not be found

When using the Release-build configuration it tries to referece to the path **\bin\Release\net5.0-windows** which I think does not make any sense because the Class library targets the framework type **net5.0**. Also after checking the folders the Class library indeed puts the built files into a folder called **net5.0**.

Problem is I don't know where I can change that or if there is a workaround for that issue.
I have already updated to the newest VisualStudio version (16.9.0), since I thought maybe it's because ClickOnce way newly implemented in Vs, but this did not solve the issue.
Publishing to a Folder works. Azure I don't have, so I cannot try that.

Can anybody help me with this issue?
Also if you need more information, I'm happy to provide it.

Comment: You mention that you are using VS2019. Which specific version are you using? Just in case it's advised to use the [most recent release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes): currently16.9.0. Maybe that might help.

Comment: @SebastianInones As mentioned in the text I am using Version 16.9.0.

Comment: my apologies, I missed that part when you mentioned the version.
Have you tried to check Windows Event Viewer just in case it provides you with some hints?

Comment: @SebastianInones thanks for the idea! unfortunatly it does not show any errors/warnings :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this reported issue and the error looks like yours:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/clickonce-publish-for-net-core-31-and-net-50-may-f/1275937
Copied with little changes from the thread above:
It seems the publish command seeks the files in the same target runtime as the published project, even though it could be different (and builds succesfully outside the publish command).
The issue occurs even when the app targets net5.0-windows and the class library is net5.0.
The workaround is to select a specific **Target Runtime** (i.e. win-x64) on the Configuration page of the Publish Wizard instead of using the default **Portable**.